# Category of monoids with set endomaps via comma or others constructions

Tags: category-theory, terminology, definition

I'm interested in finding a known category  theory costruction of new categories from given ones, e.g. comma, functor categories, cat. of elements and so on.

**Example**: given a category $C$ we can define $M{\rm Act}(C)$ to be the category where objects are actions of the monoid $M$ on objects of $C$ via $C$-endomorphism, i.e.  pairs $(X,\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in M}:X\to X)$ s.t. $$f_{\alpha\cdot_M\beta}=f_\alpha\circ_Cf_\beta$$
In this case we have
$$M{\rm Act}(C)=[{\bf B}M,C]$$

I'd like instead to form a category whose objects are pairs $(M,\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in L}:UM\to UM)$ where $M,L$ are monoids, $U$ is the forgetful functor from monoids to sets, but $L$ acts via set endomaps, without the need of conserving the monoid structure of $M$.
Call that category $U_{L,\rm Mon}$.

> **Question 1.** The question is to find a costruction  that gives $$L,{\rm Mon}\mapsto U_{L,\rm Mon}$$
> The goal I have in mind is to get
> $$L{\rm Act}({\rm Mon})\hookrightarrow U_{L,\rm Mon}$$

An elementary instance of this would be the category of monoids equipped with sets endomaps or permutation of the elements, i.e. of pairs $(M,f:UM\to UM)$.

**Effort.** I tried to attempt a comma costruction but I can't make it work. I tried to consider as first functor the inclusion of the "singleton" subcategory of $\rm Cat$ consisting only of ${\bf B} L$ and the other functor sending a monoid to its underling set and then to the delooping of its endomaps monoid $$M\mapsto UM\mapsto UM^{UM}\mapsto {\bf B}UM^{UM}$$

The first problem with this is that I don't see achieving functoriaty unless I restrict to the groupoid of monoids and isomorphisms or to some kind of category with "twisted pair of maps". Even then I feel, but I haven't checked, that the morphisms of the resulting comma categories won't match with my expectations for $U_{L,\rm Mon}$.

**Effort 2.**  I tried with the pullback of $U:\rm Mon\to \rm Set$ along a functor ${\bf B}L\to \rm Set$. But again, I can't understand if the morphisms matches the expected ones and even they do, it seems that I'd have to sum up in some way all the fibers for every ${\bf B}L\to \rm Set$ or some objects will be missing.

Comment: @S.C. Damn, I guess you are right! I want as morphisms functions that respect the monoid and the action, i.e. pairs of L action morphisms and monoid morphisms.... that happen to be the same se theoretic function on the underlying set... so I guess that the pullback is the right choice. It a subcategory of the product of LAct and Mon of pairs that agree on the underlying set. Thanks. Feel free to make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want the pullback of the forgetful functors $L$-$\rm Act(\mathcal{Set}) \to \mathcal{Set}$ and $\mathcal{Mon} \to \mathcal{Set}$ since you basically want actions of $L$ on sets that happen to be the underlying set of a monoid.

The objects of this pullback are (equivalent to) pairs $(M, \cdot_M)$ where $M$ is a monoid and $\cdot_M$ is a a left $L$-action on $U M$. The morphisms $(M, \cdot_M) \to (N, \cdot_N)$ are monoid homomorphisms $f \colon M \to N$ which also preserve the action of $L$, i.e. $f(g \cdot_M x) = g \cdot_N f(x)$ for all $g \in L$ and $x \in U M$.

Comment: I think you mean the pullback of $\text{$L$-Act}(\mathbf{Set}) → \mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{Mon} → \mathbf{Set}$ instead.

Comment: @Idéophage, whoops, yeah, thanks for catching that